# Problem building c# Application using Squirrel

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application, squirrel

I am working on an application that does some of my office works. It was working fine. I used Squirrel to update and deploy the application. However, It was okay until my application was 1.1.6. After that, from 1.1.7, my application is not updating. And I've tried to uninstall the application, and install a new updated version of the application, but still, v 1.1.6 is installed. Is there any limit to building app using Squirrel? or is something wrong when building the app in the release configuration? It is working all okay in debug configuration.

Comment: Which Squirrel version do you use? when you say your application v 1.1.6 worked and v 1.1.7 does not, the question is which changes have you made? or did I misunderstood some thing!

Comment: I'm using squirrel 1.9.0. Yes, I've made some changes inside 2 classes in v 1.1.7, like change the calculation steps, and generate a report in a different style..